# Partially replace string using 'sed' shell command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I need to delete the <#> in the following pattern:

```
vdd1a<1>  
vdd1b<2>  
vdd1c<3>  
....
```

Outputs should be like:

```
vdd1a  
vdd1b  
vdd1c  
...
```

I was trying to do this    `sed 's/\(vdd1[a-z]*\).<[0-9]>/\1/' file1 > file2`

But it gives me "vdd1" all the way.

How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot `.` after the paren is matching the letter after the 1. You need to get rid of it. I.e.,

```
sed 's/\(vdd1[a-z]*\)<[0-9]>/\1/' file1 > file2
```

Alternatively, you can just replace the `<[0-9]>` with a blank pattern, i.e.,

```
sed 's/<[0-9]>//' file1 > filed
```

Comment: Thanks toth, I have other patterns in this file like "vdd3<#>" which I don't wanna touch.

Answer (score 0):

If the lines don't contain another `<` besides the one in the `<#>` part, you can avoid using `sed` and use something like `cut` instead, for example:

```
cut -d"<" -f1 <<< "vdd1a<1>"
```

Will print:

```
vdd1a
```

Invoking it with the files:

```
cut -d"<" -f1 < file1 > file2
```

Comment: Thanks higuaro, I have other patterns in this file like "vdd3a<#>" and some other ..<#>.. stuffs which I don't wanna touch.